# Disposing Brushes

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, system.drawing

I am having a few memory problems with a long running application; I have been inspecting the paint methods to insure that brushes are properly disposed. In the case where the `Brush` is created in the argument to the function, will the brush be disposed after the call?

The case is outlined below:

```
     g.DrawString(valueText, Font, new SolidBrush(Color.Red),
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am not entirely certain, but I don't believe it is.  This would be safer:

```
using(var redBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red)
{
    g.DrawString(valueText, Font, redBrush);
}
```

Comment: What about using Brushes.Red ? No need to instantiate those. And you must not dispose them, so no 'using(....)' either

Comment: Since this compiles it means the brush is disposable and thus it should be disposed of.

Answer (score 4):

No, you should do it manually. Do however examine the classes [`Brushes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.brushes.aspx) and [`SystemBrushes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.systembrushes.aspx), for ready-made brushes that you can use without creating new ones (and that you also don't need to / should not dispose).

Comment: You cannot Dispose the stock brushes. If you try it will throw.